# How to break up a letter after every intersection in inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, path

I have the following letter in my inkscape:

[image]

I have the following XML generated from the above letter.

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qncg4jew/)**

The main portion of the letter is ofcoure the below XML:

```
<path
       style="color:#000000;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:40px;line-height:125%;font-family:sans-serif;text-indent:0;text-align:start;text-decoration:none;text-decoration-line:none;text-decoration-style:solid;text-decoration-color:#000000;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;text-transform:none;direction:ltr;block-progression:tb;writing-mode:lr-tb;baseline-shift:baseline;text-anchor:start;white-space:normal;clip-rule:nonzero;display:inline;overflow:visible;visibility:visible;opacity:1;isolation:auto;mix-blend-mode:normal;color-interpolation:sRGB;color-interpolation-filters:linearRGB;solid-color:#000000;solid-opacity:1;fill:none;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#0000ff;stroke-width:6;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1;color-rendering:auto;image-rendering:auto;shape-rendering:auto;text-rendering:auto;enable-background:accumulate"
       d="m 407.88415,333.72984 -25.70508,93.04297 -26.77344,-93.00391 -3.56445,3.21094 -30.25977,27.26171 0,134.33008 35.26758,31.77149 0,-78.57031 25.4375,66.86132 24.19727,-65.87695 0,77.58594 35.26757,-31.77149 0,-134.33008 -33.86718,-30.51171 z"
       id="path4206"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
```

Now what i want to achieve is multiple paths , that is break up this **M** further , so that every straight line is a path and after every intersection the path is not continued , How do i do this in inkscape ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the path, then activate the node tool (<kbd>F2</kbd>).

Drag with the mouse over the whole figure, so all nodes are selected.

Then click on the *Break path at selected nodes* icon. At this point you still have 1 path, but with disjoint segments.

Now go to *Path -> Break Apart*. This will leave several independent paths, one for each original segment.

One problem when breaking the path into segments is that you will lose the miter joins. If you want to keep them, you should start with *Path -> Stroke to path* and then operate from there, but you will have a lot of nodes to care about.